# Understanding Jetty Resource and Context in WAR and other deployments

Tags: servlets, jetty, war

Jetty has Resource and Contexts.  I'm trying to understand them better.

Is a Resource a URL, a file path, or something else? Is Resource relative to the WAR, the filesystem its running on, or something else? How do you point a Resource to something inside the WAR?

What is a resourceBase? How does it affect resources?

And is Context just a way of saying the beginning of the URL path? If not, what is Context?

I've read the API docs but do not see these defined.

Answer (score 0):

The word "Resource" is overloaded.

- Resource is the term used in the HTTP spec when making a request to any URL (see ["Target Resource"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.1))
- Resource is the second letter in the acronym URL (Uniform Resource Locator) and URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
- Resource is also a definition for something that can be accessed by the server machine itself:

  - a filesystem path as a String (`/path/to/my/...`) reference to that path.
  - a filesystem path as a String URL (`file://...`) reference to that path.
  - a String URL (`http://...`) reference to non-filesystem resource.
  - a Classpath reference (`/content/in/classpath`)
  - a Jar File reference (`jar:file:///path/to/foo.jar!/path/inside/`)
  - a `java.io.File` referece.
  - a `java.nio.file.Path` reference.
  - a `java.net.URL` reference (can be any supported java url protocol/scheme).
  - a `java.net.URI` reference (can be any supported java url protocol/scheme).
- A Resource can be a reference to a specific thing that has content (like a file) or a directory of other Resources.
- A "Resource Base" is always a directory style reference.
- A request for content within a "Resource Base" is always relative to that Resource Base and has protection to keep you in that Resource Base (or throw an error).  (eg: Resource Base of `/path/to/base/` and a request of `/css/main.css` will return `/path/to/base/css/main.css`, but requesting `/../../../secret.txt` will return a an error)

Now, the word "Context", this is what you see in the Servlet spec itself in the concept of `javax.servlet.ServletContext`

- Defines a set of resources (physical, static, dynamic, generated, etc) that can be accessed via a common context path.
- Processes (eg: servlets and filters) within that context can access the other resources within that context.
- Processes outside of the context cannot access content within that context.
- The Context itself holds information that all components within that context can access (eg: Attributes, init-parameters, security constraints, security roles, mime-type mappings, locale-encodings, session configuration, listeners, temp directories, work directories, etc..)